# Using IF NOT EXISTS to Create Functions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, stored-functions

first post here...

I have a number of SQL scripts which I have to manually run each time to create missing functions and stored procedures when I install an SSRS Reporting Suite.

Ideally I would like to automate this in one piece of code so was looking at the IF NOT EXIST statement.

My idea would be... check if function exits, if Y move to next script, if N, run the CREATE FUNCTION script then move to next script:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[report].[fnR_ActiveCustomers]') 
AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))

CREATE FUNCTION [report].[fnR_ActiveCustomers]
(... etc etc
```

When I start this I get: "create function must be the only statement in the batch".

Can anyone assist me please?

Thanks
Lee

Answer (score 0):

Use `GO` in between to separate batches:

```
IF NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[report].[fnR_ActiveCustomers]') 
AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
Go
CREATE FUNCTION [report].[fnR_ActiveCustomers]
(... etc etc
```

Comment: Are you sure this works?

Comment: Yes, it will work. GO acts as batch separator so that Create statement will be in a separate batch and also the first statement in the batch.

Comment: Try it... Without a DROP below the IF there's not sense in the first batch...

Comment: It is checking for if not exists then create which makes sense

Comment: I don't see how this could work (I tried it without success) - FWIK, the if clause needs to be in the same batch as the script it will run on a successful condition. It doesn't answer the top question, but i think Shnugo is right, you'd want to use a If exists statement and then drop the function if it exists.